Automation for cloud based VBA-code enabled excel workbook
I have a excel sheet which contains VBA-code to connect to an API in order to retrieve daily data, which in the end is added to the bottom row of several tabs in the workbook.
Everyday I open this workbook and click on the button in order to get data from the previous day. But I havnt figured out a way to automate this at example 8:00 AM.
Is there a way to automate it, so that I dont start the computer, open the worksheet, click on the button and after it has done its API-retrieval and calculations (which takes about 10-20 min) and then save the workbook. The best would be if it is totally automated (ie I dont even have to start my computer).
Can I for instance achieve this with Microsoft Powerautomate somehow? Can I perhaps achieve this if I use google sheets instead?

If you don't want to use (eg) Windows Task Scheduler to run your macro automatically then this is not really a VBA question...

@Tim I think the question is about exactly of that. (only diff. OP idea is with PowerAutomate)

It looks like you can use an API with Power Automate, so that would be a good option provided your workbook is stored in Sharepoint or OneDrive. https://forwardforever.com/how-to-use-an-api-with-power-automate/
